# How do I swap the Windows and Control keys in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remapping

I'm used to a Mac keyboard and that means my finger expect to find the shortcut key to the left of the spacebar. How can I turn the Windows key--command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) key on a Mac keyboard) into the Control key and vice versa?

Answer (score 42):

Quite simply, use this [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script. (Tutorial on how to create a script [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s12))

```
RCtrl::RWin
RWin::RCtrl
LCtrl::LWin
LWin::LCtrl
```

Works for all but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.

A workaround for allowing simultaneous <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>, is to map left to right, and right to left (as opposed to left-left, right-right) i.e..

```
LAlt::RCtrl
RAlt::LCtrl
RCtrl::LAlt
LCtrl::RAlt
```

Disclaimer: this answer may no longer be relevant in modern Windows 10/11 versions as it was written originally for Windows 7.

Comment: bottom section does not work anymore, gives an error of duplicate keys, i tested this on windows 8.1 on a macbook air and ctrl alt del works normally without a script

Comment: I just used LWin:LCtrl, as I don't use RWin for Control much. Nice suggestion.

Comment: On my Lenovo Ideapad 110 W10 Xmas 2017 special, the uparrow key is where every other shift key in the world is located. So I swapped them using AutoHotKey:  https://pastebin.com/eEYb7kT1. I had to start the script with 'Run as Administrator' so that programs started as administrator (say, cmd.exe) would see the remapping.

Answer (score 14):

### Warning

This answer was first posted on 22/4/2017. Please verify that everything in it is still applicable, and make corrections to this answer, as needed.

### SharpKeys

[SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) *is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows to remap one key to any other key*.

### Apply Key Swap

Swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys through a two step process. Using SharpKeys, map:

1. `Left Alt (00_38)` to `Left Ctrl (00_1D)`
2. `Left Ctrl (00_1D)` to `Left Alt (00_38)`

Presumably you can do similar things to a right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

I successfully applied the two step remapping to Windows 10 as of 2017/04/21.

### Remove Key Swap

By choosing **Delete All** and following that up with **Write to Registry** in SharpKeys I was able to delete the registry key that SharpKeys created in the first place. You could also manually delete the relevant registry key using regedit.

### Background

[How to Disable Caps Lock Key in Windows 7, 8, 10, or Vista](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) provides a nice explanation of the registry key that SharpKeys modifies (creates?). I've posted my registry key FYI.

After SharpKeys ran, my registry key:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map`

Contained:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`
`03 00 00 00 1D 00 38 00`
`38 00 1D 00 00 00 00 00`

A separate SuperUser question provides a bit of extra context: [How to remap Right-Win and Right-Alt keyboard keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1197883/how-to-remap-right-win-and-right-alt-keyboard-keys) and Mehper C. Palavuzlar's answer to this question pointed me in the right direction. Rather than edit his question, I thought it more appropriate to post my answer as a separate answer.

### Editorial comment

It does feel nice to be able to do cut, copy and paste with the thumb and <kbd>Alt</kbd> rather than the awkward pinky reach required with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in Windows. But, even though I grew up a Mac user (25 years) and would dearly love to be able to use my thumb (a natural position) to activate short cuts in Windows, I think it'll be too confusing to do a whole-sale swap of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> *for me*. For example, <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> are in the same spot so remapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> just won't work. Too bad that Apple made the right decision (thumb-based short cuts) and Microsoft went with the not-so-logical "industry standard" of its day. But, I guess "industry standard" is how we ended up typing with QWERTY and all its inglorious variants in the first place.

PS Windows still has **three** command keys?! Apple's solution of one modifier key for special letters and one for short cuts was a sensible design choice and allowed for easy access to less common (in English) but still important symbols and diacrits (e.g. °, ´, ¸, ˆ, ¨). In Windows you've got <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> all doing essentially the same thing and, I find that the vast majority of users rarely, if ever use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> shortcuts. Plus <kbd>Alt</kbd> gets especially confusing since it's sometimes a method to enter non-standard characters with the keypad or with AltGr but it's **also** a short-cut modifier at times). But, I digress... I've inspired myself to search for or ask an actual question.

Comment: Docs has been updated and explicitly says that one can swap keys "Things that SharpKeys will do... Allow you to swap two keys with each other - e.g. you can swap Left Windows with Left Control and vice versa". I can also confirm this, have swapped my Win <> Alt keys since I'm using a Mac-keyboard for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this AutoHotkey script that pretty much brings the mac keyboard experience to Windows.

https://github.com/stroebjo/autohotkey-windows-mac-keyboard

> This AutoHotkey configuration file makes usual keyboard shortcuts work with an Apple keyboard on Windows. It has been testet with a german keyboard layout, but should work under different layouts as well.

Comment: This solution seems the better so far. Simple swapping Keys do not provide a consistent experience on some layout (like Italian keywords) because some Alt+keys stops to work.
With the suggested script it works fair better so far.

Answer (score 5):

Use [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) from Microsoft, it makes remapping any keyboard keys for windows 11 easier.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How-to Geek has a nice solution for your request:

[Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 7 / XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Comment: This won't work as SharpKeys (which that page tells you to install) won't let you swap two keys!