# How can I use Mac-style shortcuts in Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, shortcuts

Is there a way which I can use mac-style shortcuts in Windows?

My personal computer is a Macbook, but my work computer is a Windows PC.
Using keyboard shortcuts is a nightmare...

Like the copy command. I want to use `Windows + C`, not `Ctrl + C`.

Searching in google just gives me how to use Windows-style shortcuts on Mac, not the opposite.

Comment: There's a open-source script for AutoHotkey that does that: https://gist.github.com/jitbit/e948cf198f54cbf3992c

Answer (score 1):

I read a post recently that says that some Windows system shortcuts' keys are defined inside DLL's, so they're in some manner hardcoded (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>). But shortcuts inside other apps depend on how they were programmed, so I think you're stuck with them unless the app itself provides some way to change the mapping. It's that or mapping/switching the <kbd>Win/Super</kbd> key with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key using a 3rd party software like they state in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/135539/how-do-i-swap-the-windows-and-control-keys-in-windows-7):

> Quite simply, use this AutoHotKey script
>
> RCtrl::RWin
>
> RWin::RCtrl
>
> LCtrl::LWin
>
> LWin::LCtrl
>
> Works for all but Ctrl + Alt + Del.

I assume `AutoHotKey` is that software

Good luck.