# Enable Windows+C/V as a copy-paste combination in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Using Mac at home has taught me to rely on command+c/v combination for copying and pasting.

I am almost sure my previous Windows 10 laptop at work allowed me to copy and paste with Windows+C/V. The new one loaded with Windows 10 Pro does not and I don't seem to be able to find where I could set it up.

Is there a way in Windows 10 to enable copy and paste with Windows+C/V combination, still retaining Ctrl+C/V or without it.

Thank you.

Comment: I would try one of the generic automation tools, e.g. AutoHotkey seems to be a common recommendation.

Comment: Windows+c and Windows+V has never been a default shortcut for copy and paste that has always been CTLR+v and CTLR+C

Comment: What you want to do is essentially switch the Windows and Control keys, which as grawity said can be done with AutoHotkey. Read this other post for your answer: https://superuser.com/questions/135539/how-do-i-swap-the-windows-and-control-keys-in-windows

Comment: In the newest versions of windows "Win+V" acts as the clipboard history, so that is a useful shortcut already. I use AutoHotKey to remap Win+C to copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very old question, but I was having the same issue moving back and forth between Mac for work and Windows for personal device. The [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) app has a Keyboard Manager where you can remap and key combinations.

[PowerToys Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Av8.png)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks!

As Win-X opens the Power User menu, I remapped that to Win-Alt-X

Comment: I would suggest remapping to `ctrl+insert` for copy, and `shift+insert` for paste as those work in most situations (ctrl+c/v doesn't copy paste in a terminal)